# libtorrent python dht example

Tags: python, p2p, dht, libtorrent

I am trying to implement a p2p application. I want to use DHT in libtorrent library. I would like to use python for p2p application. Can anyone suggest an example dht libtorrent python implementation or some api that I can use?

Comment: Look at my project qadom that implements DHT https://github.com/amirouche/qadom

Answer (score 1):

[Deluge](https://github.com/deluge-torrent/deluge) is well supported implementation of libtorrent in python which supports DHT

Also DHT is enabled by default in libtorrent, even in the python bindings.